# Redis int representation of a string is bigger when the string is more than 7 bytes but smaller otherwise

Tags: optimization, redis, int

I'm trying to reduce Redis's objects size as much as I can and I've taken this whole week to experiment with it.

While testing different data representations I found out that an int representation of the string "hello" results in a smaller object. It may not look like much, but if you have a lot of data it can make a difference between using a few GB memory vs dozens of it.

Look at the following example (you can try it yourself if you want):

```
> SET test:1 "hello"
> debug object test:1
> Value at:0xb6c9f380 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:6 lru:9535350 lru_seconds_idle:7
```

In particular you should look at **serializedlength** which is 6 (bytes) in this case.

Now, look at the following int representation of it:

```
> SET test:2 "857715"
> debug object test:2
> Value at:0xb6c9f460 refcount:1 encoding:int serializedlength:5 lru:9535401 lru_seconds_idle:2
```

As you see, it results in a byte shorter object (note also **encoding:int** which I think is suggesting that ints get handled in a more efficient way).

With the string "hello w" (you'll see in a few moments why I didn't use "hello world" instead) we get an even bigger saving when it's represented as an int:

```
> SET test:3 "hello w"
> SET test:4 "857715023" <- Int representation. Notice that I inserted a "0", if I don't, it results in a bigger object and the encoding is set to "raw" instead (after all a space is not an int).
>
> debug object test:3
> Value at:0xb6c9f3a0 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:8 lru:9535788 lru_seconds_idle:6
> debug object test:4
> Value at:0xb6c9f380 refcount:1 encoding:int serializedlength:5 lru:9535809 lru_seconds_idle:5
```

It looks cool as long as you don't exceed 7 bytes string.. Look at what happens by a "hello wo" int representation:

```
> SET test:5 "hello wo"
> SET test:6 "85771502315"
>
> debug object test:5
> Value at:0xb6c9f430 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:9 lru:9535907 lru_seconds_idle:9
> debug object test:6
> Value at:0xb6c9f470 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:12 lru:9535913 lru_seconds_idle:5
```

As you can see the int (12 bytes) is bigger than the string representation (9 bytes).

My question here is, what's going on behind the scenes when you represent a string as an int, that it is smaller until you reach 7 bytes?

Is there a way to increase this limit as you do with "list-max-ziplist-entries/list-max-ziplist-value" or a clever way to optimize this process so that it always (or nearly) results in a smaller object than a string?

**UPDATE**

I've further experimented with other tricks, and you can actually have smaller ints than string, regardless of its size, but that would involve a little more work as of data structure modelling.

I've found out that if you split the int representation of a string in chunks of ~8 numbers each, it ends up being smaller.

Take as an example the word "Hello World Hi Universe" and create both a **string** and **int** SET:

```
> HMSET test:7 "Hello" "World" "Hi" "Universe"
> HMSET test:8 "74111114" "221417113" "78" "2013821417184"
```

The results are as follows:

```
> debug object test:7
> Value at:0x7d12d600 refcount:1 encoding:ziplist serializedlength:40 lru:9567096 lru_seconds_idle:296
>
> debug object test:8
> Value at:0x7c17d240 refcount:1 encoding:ziplist serializedlength:37 lru:9567531 lru_seconds_idle:2
```

As you can see we got the **int** set smaller by **3** bytes.

The problem in this will be *how* to organize such a thing, but it shows that it's possible nonetheless.

Still, don't know where this limit is set. The ~700K persistent use of memory (even when you have no data inside) makes me think that there is a pre-defined "pool" dedicated to the optimization of int sets.

**UPDATE2**

I think I've found where this intset "pool" is defined in Redis source.

At line *81* in the file **redis.h** there is the def **REDIS_SHARED_INTEGERS** set to **10000**

[REDISH_SHARED_INTEGERS](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/redis.h#L81)

I suspect it's the one defining the limit of an intset byte length.

I have to try to recompile it with an higher value and see if I can use a longer int value (it'll most probably allocate more memory if it's the one I think of).

**UPDATE3**

I want to thank Antirez for the reply! Didn't expect that.

As he made me notice, *len != memory usage*.

I got further in my experiment and saw that the objects get already slightly compressed (serialized). I may have missed something from the Redis documentation.

The confirmation comes from analyzing a Redis key wih the command *redis-memory-for-key **key***, which actually returns the memory usage and not the serialized length.

For example, let's take the "hello" string and int we used before, and see what's the result:

```
~ # redis-memory-for-key test:1
Key             "test:1"
Bytes               101
Type            string
~ #
~ # redis-memory-for-key test:2
Key             "test:2"
Bytes           87
Type            string
```

As you can notice the intset is smaller (87 bytes) than the string (101 bytes) anyway.

**UPDATE4**

Surprisingly a longer intset seems to affect its *serializedlength* but not memory usage..

This makes it possible to actually build a 2digit-char mapping while it still being more memory efficient than a string, without even chunking it.

By 2digit-char mapping I mean that instead of mapping "hello" to "85121215" we map it to digits with a fixed length of 2 each, prefixing it with "0" if digit < 10 like "0805121215".

A custom script would then proceed by taking every two digit apart and converting them to their equivalent char:

```
08 05 12 12 15
\  |  |   |  /
 h e  l   l o
```

This is enough to avoid disambiguation (like "o" and "ae" which both result in the digit "15").

I'll show you this works by creating another set and therefore analyzing its memory usage like I did before:

```
> SET test:9 "0805070715"

Unix shell
----------
~ # redis-memory-for-key test:9
Key             "test:9"
Bytes           87
Type            string
```

You can see that we have a memory win here.

The same "hello" string compressed with Smaz for comparison:

```
>>> smaz.compress('hello')
'\x10\x98\x06'

// test:10 would be unfair as it results in a byte longer object
SET post:1 "\x10\x98\x06"

~ # redis-memory-for-key post:1
Key            "post:1"
Bytes          99
Type           string
```

Comment: For everyone looking into this, I suggest to look into data compression if you don't want to waste a lot of time thinking how to structure this. You can compress a compressed string even further than an int set can. Something that comes in mind is that you can replace the many zeroes with something shorter like: x(n-0) where *n-0* is the number of zeroes (ex. 0 0 0 0 0 becomes x5). You could potentially compress/decompress a string client side with Javascript workers not to stress the server CPU too much and have consistent speed.

Comment: Sorry typing from phone: serialized len != men usage.

Comment: @antirez No problem! In fact I really didn't expect the reply from you, the author of Redis. I've added an update reflecting your comment. I've read http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization before diving into more optimization experiments myself, and I feel that there could be added more optimization techniques to that page.

Comment: Note that your encoding to int loses information: How do you distinguish between "o" and "ae"?

Comment: @robx As you've noticed that's the most difficult part actually. A possible way could be to map every char to 2 digits (like 010203 instead of 123 and 010515 instead of 1515) so that you could develop a script which takes every two digits apart and convert them to their char equivalents. I analyzed the memory usage with using this technique and it's surprisingly smaller than a string anyway (87 bytes as the other int with inefficient mapping vs the 101 bytes string). Unfortunately I had to reinstall my OS but I'll try to increase the shared_integers value and see if that changes for good.

Comment: As a final note, Smaz looks like to be the clear winner when it comes to a large number of db objects. With 1M objects there is no difference in size between strings and ints, but Smaz brought a ~20 saving overall.

Answer (score 4):

> My question here is, what's going on behind the scenes when you represent a
>   string as an int, that it is smaller until you reach 7 bytes?

Notice that the integer you supplied as test #6 is no longer actually encoded
as an integer, but as raw:

> SET test:6 "85771502315"
>
> Value at:0xb6c9f470 refcount:1 encoding:raw serializedlength:12 lru:9535913 lru_seconds_idle:

So we see that a "raw" value occupies one byte plus the length of its string representation. In memory
you get that plus the overhead of the value.

The integer encoding, I suspect, encodes a number as a 32-bit integer; then it will always
need five bytes, one to tell its type, and four to store those 32 bits.

As soon as you overflow the maximum representable integer in 32 bits, which is either 2 billions or 4 depending on whether you use a sign or not, you need to revert to raw encoding.

So probably

```
2147483647 -> five bytes     (TYPE_INT 0x7F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF)
2147483649 -> eleven bytes   (TYPE_RAW '2'  '1'  '4'  '7'  '4'  '8'  '3'  '6'  '4'  '9')
```

Now, how can you squeeze a string representation PROVIDED THAT YOU ONLY USE AN ASCII SET?

You can get the string (140 characters):

```
When in the Course of human events it becomes necessary for one people
to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another
```

and convert each character to a six-bit representation; basically its index in the string

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz56789."
```

which is the set of all the characters you can use.

You can now encode four such "text-only characters" in three "binary characters", a sort of "reverse base 64 encoding"; base64 encoding will get three binary characters and create a four-byte sequence of ASCII characters.

If we were to code it as groups of integers, we would save a few bytes - maybe get it down
to 130 bytes - at the cost of a larger overhead.

With this type of "reverse base64" encoding, we can get 140 character to 35 groups of four characters, which become a string of 35x3 = 105 binary characters, raw encoded to 106 bytes.

As long, I repeat, as you *never use characters outside the range above*. If you do, you can
enlarge the range to 128 characters and 7 bits, thus saving 12.5% instead of 25%; 140 characters will then become 126, raw encoded to 127 bytes, and you save (141-127) = 14 bytes.

## Compression

If you have much longer strings, you can **compress** them (i.e., you use a function such as `deflate()` or `gzencode()` or `gzcompress()` ). Either straight; in which case the above string becomes 123 bytes. Easy to do.

## Compressing many small strings: the [Rube Goldberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) approach

Since compression algorithms learn, and at the beginning they dare assume nothing, small strings will not compress greatly. They're "all beginning", so to speak. Just as an engine, when running cold the performances are inferior.

If you have a "corpus" of text these strings come from, you can use a time-consuming trick that "warms up" the compression engine and may double (or better) its performances.

Suppose you have two strings, `COMMON` and `TARGET` (the second one is the one you're interested in). If you z-compressed `COMMON` you would get, say, `ZCMN`. If you compressed `TARGET` you would get `ZTRGT`.

But as I said, since the gz compression algorithm is *stream oriented*, and it *learns* as it goes by, the compression ratio of the second half of any text (*provided there aren't freakish statistical distribution changes between halves*) is always appreciably higher than that of the first half.

So if you were to compress, say, `COMMONTARGET`, you'd get `ZCMGHQI`.

Notice that the first part of the string, as far as almost the end, is the same as before. Indeed if you compressed `COMMONFOOBAR`, you'd get something like `ZCMQKL`. And the second part is compressed better than before, even if we count the area of overlap as belonging entirely to the second string.

And this is the trick. Given a family of strings (`TARGET`, `FOOBAR`, `CASTLE BRAVO`), we compress not the strings, but the *concatenation* of those strings with **a large prefix**. Then we *discard* from the result the common compressed prefix. Thus `TARGET` is taken from the compression of `COMMONTARGET` (which is `ZCMGHQI`), and becomes `GHQI` instead of `ZTRGT`, with a 20% gain.

The decoder does the reverse: given `GHQI`, it first applies the common compressed prefix `ZCM` (*which it must know*); then it decodes the result, and finally discards the common uncompressed prefix, of which it need only know the length beforehand.

So the first sentence above (140 characters) becomes 123 when compressed by itself; if I take the rest of the Declaration and use it as a prefix, it compresses to 3355 bytes. This prefix plus my 140 bytes becomes 3409 bytes, of which 3352 are common, leaving 57 bytes.

At the cost of storing once the uncompressed prefix in the encoder, and the compressed prefix once in the decoder, **and the whole thingamajig running five times as slow**, I can now get those 140 bytes down to 57 instead of 123 - less than half of before.

This trick works great for small strings; for larger ones, the advantage isn't worth the pain. Also, different prefixes yield different results. The best prefixes are those that contain most of the sequences that are *likely to appear* in the string pool, ordered by increasing length.

Added bonus: the compressed prefix also doubles as a sort of weak encryption, as without that, you can't easily decode the compressed strings, even if you *might* be able to recover some pieces thereof.